# C++ Running multiple class functions

Tags: c++

So i have this code

```
MemoryClass memory;

MyClass mC(false, memory);
```

loaded in main then i do

```
std::thread tMC(mC.run, memory);
```

Which doesn't works. What i want to do is to call `mC.run(memory)` with the thread

My final goal would be to have a main while loop, and if needed run the sub functions in it without interruption. I need this to make a software that will be console based, and when for example you press "A" will run a certain function then if you press "B" will run the two at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the method itself and then pass the implicit `this` argument and your `memory`:

```
std::thread tMC(&MyClass::run, &mC, memory);
```

Comment: I tried that but it makes my whole software crash

Comment: @NotanNimda That has other causes beyond the scope of this question. Most likely a dangling pointer or reference.

Comment: Alright then, i guess its time to debug. Thanks

Comment: If i need to input multiple args should i just and a comma and the var ?